# Glyphicons on Bootstrap are not showing correctly on certain site areas

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons, glyphicons

For example, here in my homepage: http://www.klayz.com/ they work correctly (they are in the navbar and you can see them one at the left and one at the right)

But here: http://articoli.klayz.com/ they are not showing. Here one is shown and another is shown with a strange character: giochi.klayz.com/index.php.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I just solved opening the headers files of my scripts and adding this code:

```
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now they are working. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the path to the folder is correctly specified.

Comment: Hi O'Brien, I'm just not specifing the path to the folder. I'm including them like this:

     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you tried loading it in a different browser?

Comment: I was using firefox, anyway now I solved! Thank you for your replies O'Brien! :)